# Convert Notes to Hertz (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, midi

I have tried to write a function that takes in notes in MIDI form (C2,A4,Bb6) and returns their respective frequencies in hertz.  I'm not sure what the best method of doing this should be.  I am torn between two approaches.  1) a list based one where I can switch on an input and return hard-coded frequency values given that I may only have to do this for 88 notes (in the grand piano case).  2) a simple mathematical approach however my math skills are a limitation as well as converting the input string into a numerical value.  Ultimately I've been working on this for a while and could use some direction.

Comment: Good idea. Do that. Did you have a question?

Comment: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function based on this formula:

> The basic formula for the frequencies of the notes of the equal
> tempered scale is given by
>
> fn = f0 * (a)n
>
> where
>
> f0 = the frequency of one fixed note which must be defined. A common choice is setting the A above middle C (A4) at f0 = 440 Hz.
>
> n = the number of half steps away from the fixed note you are. If you are at a higher note, n is positive. If you are on a lower note, n is negative.
>
> fn = the frequency of the note n half steps away. a = (2)1/12 = the twelth root of 2 = the number which when multiplied by itself 12 times equals 2 = 1.059463094359...

[http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/NoteFreqCalcs.html](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/NoteFreqCalcs.html)

In Objective-C, this would be:

```
+ (double)frequencyForNote:(Note)note withModifier:(Modifier)modifier inOctave:(int)octave {
    int halfStepsFromA4 = note - A;
    halfStepsFromA4 += 12 * (octave - 4);
    halfStepsFromA4 += modifier;

    double frequencyOfA4 = 440.0;
    double a = 1.059463094359;

    return frequencyOfA4 * pow(a, halfStepsFromA4);
}
```

With the following enums defined:

```
typedef enum : int {
    C = 0,
    D = 2,
    E = 4,
    F = 5,
    G = 7,
    A = 9,
    B = 11,
} Note;

typedef enum : int {
    None = 0,
    Sharp = 1,
    Flat = -1,
} Modifier;
```

https://gist.github.com/NickEntin/32c37e3d31724b229696

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be posted in the relevant language. It will help with future searches of this question also looking for an Objective-C solution.

Comment: Whoops, for some reason I thought this was tagged `ios`, not `objective-c`.  Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [MIDI pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Tuning_Standard)?

[image]

where f is the frequency, and d the MIDI data.